# Passing model from one action to another asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, action

I have a controller named `ErrorController` with an action `Index`.

I am capturing exceptions from other controllers namely `HomeController` and storing the exceptions as shown below in a model named `ExceptionDetails`

```
public class ExceptionDetail
  {
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
  }
```

Once an exception is caught I will store the it in the above shown model and want to send it to the action `Index` of the controller `ErrorController`.

How can I do that

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
catch (System.Exception exception)
  {
    exceptionDetail.details = exception.ToString();
    exceptionDetail.details = exception.Message.ToString();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { exception = exceptionDetail });
  }
```

The `Index` action is shown below and I have a strongly typed view for Index too.

```
 public ActionResult Index(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail)
  {
    return View(exceptionDetail);
  }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "didn't work"

Comment: I found the solution @Jonesy will post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your method signature is :

```
public ActionResult Index(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail)
```

so your RedirectToAction should define a parameter "exceptionDetail' :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", exceptionDetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", exceptionDetail);
```

By this way I can use the model properties at thea ction `Index` of controller `ErrorController`